# Using java code along with typescript for certain features in ionic 2 android app

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Ionic is used for creating hybrid apps supporting Windows , iOS & Android at the same time using web technologies like Html, CSS & Js . Our concern is that certain features that are not supported by I**onic 2 framework** , can we use native code to achieve them.
In case of react-native it seems possible as bigger giants like myntra , airbnb , etc are doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

So what i understand from your question is :-

- you want to create the project in ionic/phonegap technology.
- you need the help of native technologies i.e android and ios to achieve certain task.

Yes you can, that is easily possible with phonegap thats why it is said as hybrid technology.

you have to create your custom plugin for that here are few links that can help you get started with the plugin development.

[Started with phonegap plugin developemnt guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)

[This tutorial will be much helpful to you](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/)

This Git repo is the sample hello world plugin you can download, install and understand the flow.

[Sample hello world plugin Demo](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello)

Hope this will be helpful to you.